# Upper bound for the number of infected neighbors of the healthy sites of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $(V,E)$ be an undirected graph with bounded degree (i.e. $m:= \max_x\deg(x)<\infty$) and $A\subseteq V$ a finite subset. The sites in $A$ are infected, the sites in $S\setminus A$ are healthy. Let $n(x):=|\{y\in A:x\sim y\}|$ be the number of infected neighbors of $x\in S$. Why is
$$\sum_{x\in S\setminus A}n(x)\leq m|A|$$
(this is equivalent to equation $(4.36)$ in Liggett's [Continuous Time Markov Processes](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/113))? I was only able to derive a worse upper bound:
$$\sum_{x\in S\setminus A}n(x)=\sum_{x\in S\setminus A:n(x)\neq 0}n(x)\leq\sum_{x\in A}\sum_{y\sim x} n(y)\leq |A|m^2$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\sum_{x\in S\setminus A}n(x)=|\{(x,y)\in S\times S:x\in S\setminus A\land x\sim y\land y\in A\}|=&\\
&=\sum_{y\in A}\underbrace{|\{(x,y)\in S\times S:x\sim y\land x\in S\setminus A\}|}_{\leq m}\leq m|A|&
\end{align}